# Multiple spaces in Java documentation using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, documentation

For a method documentation I'd like to have multiple spaces between two words.

Like this:

[image: Text with multiple spaces between words]

Yet all I get is this in Eclipse using the `@code` and `@literal` tags:

[image: Eclipse output]

Is there a way to tell Eclipse not to remove those spaces? Because they matter to the documentation.

Thanks

**Edit:**
Thanks to David Wallace's help I realized `<pre>` is the right tag to preserve spaces. `&nbsp;` works too, but it incurs quite a bit of visual noise.

Here's a screenshot of the different tags for comparison:
[image: Different output of tags for comparison]

Comment: Not really an Eclipse issue.  You're aware that Javadocs are HTML, right?  So you could do something like using `&nbsp;` over and over.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ninja. How do you answer so quickly?

Comment: @DavidWallace: "Text inside the `@literal` inline tag is interpreted literally and not as HTML markup." That's what it says [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/javadoc_tip_code_and_literal) at least.

Comment: Thanks, @mareser - today I learnt.  My fault for being around since before Java 5, when `@literal` was introduced.

Comment: @DavidWallace: You're very welcome. Your tip regarding `&nbsp;` works: The spaces are preserved in the HTML-interpreted result, but the uninterpreted documentation looks not so nice `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...`.

Comment: How about using `<pre>`?  Is that any help?  Or even `<code>`?

Comment: Yes, `<pre>` works fine, I'm going to use that. Please put that in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @mareser I don't believe @literal or @code are meant to preserve spacing. Both tags simply cause the enclosed text not to be interpreted as HTML when *generating* the Javadoc (e.g. it converts `<` to `&lt;`). You'd have to add a `<pre>` block to preserve spacing as you do with code examples in Javadoc.